# cannot create directory new directory in /var/www

Tags: filesystems, ubuntu-11.04, readonly

I have a problem with Ubuntu 11.04. When I try to create new folder it show error "mkdir: cannot create directory `new_folder': Read-only file system ". I have no write access to any directory.

administrator@ubuntu:/var/www$ mkdir new_folder
mkdir: cannot create directory `new_folder': Read-only file system

Any body know about this please give a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `sudo` command like so:

```
$ sudo mkdir my-folder
```

This will ask for your password unless you've already used it recently, so type it in if it asks (it won't render the text for security).

If you frequently use this and are tired of entering `sudo` before everything, type `login root` and enter the password, but **BE VERY CAREFUL**! You don't want to accidentally delete any important files or do something else you can't take back!

Another solution:

If you want to give the folder write permissions, use

```
$ chmod +w my-folder
```

By default when a file is created, the user group that did so will have read, write, and execute permissions on it.

Comment: Thanks @Jwosty, I have try $ sudo mkdir my-folder but still get the same problem. Both commands above, I got the same error: "mkdir: cannot create directory `my-folde': Read-only file system"

Comment: Hmm, maybe [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-filesytem-goes-read-only.html) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
  sudo -i 
before you create a folder

or just 
 sudo mkdir

If you can't sudo then you will have to ask your admin to give you some access

Comment: thanks @Yun. When I try $sudo mkdir new_folder  It show 2 error:

sudo: Can't open /var/lib/sudo/administrator/0: Read-only file system
mkdir: cannot create directory `aaaa': Read-only file system

Comment: Try "sudo chmod +w www " in /var/

If that is successful, go in www and try create the folder with sudo mkdir

Comment: when try "sudo chmod +w www " show error: "chmod: changing permissions of `www': Read-only file system"

Comment: Were you able to create directories before this? All I can think of now is possible filesystem corruption. http://askubuntu.com/questions/23353/ubuntu-boots-into-terminal | http://askubuntu.com/questions/105793/why-has-my-file-system-turned-read-only-after-updates

Comment: yes before this I were able to create directories. The problem is because of filesystem corruption